# Set Theory negation

Tags: logic, notation

I have the value:

$x\in(-\infty, -3)\cup(4, \infty)$

The problem is, this seems like a very "brute force" solution (in my opinon) with all the $-\infty$ and $\infty$. Is there a better way to write a disjunction?

---

I am currently thinking I can write this as:

$x\in\mathbb{R}\wedge\neg[-3,4]$

What I think this should mean is all real numbers, *expect* from -3 to 4.

---

Could this also work with a disjunction?

$x\in\mathbb{R}\vee[-3,4]$

---

Does this mean the same thing? What would be the best way to write this?

Sorry is this question is not very good, I'm new here.

Comment: If you want to put it that way, the part after $\land$  could be  $\lnot(x\in[-3,4])$.  I do not view it as an improvement over what you call brute force, which is sort of missing a couple of parentheses.

Comment: @AndréNicolas What about $x\in\mathbb{R}\vee(x\in[-3,4])$, would that mean the same thing?

Comment: No, the $\lor$ is wrong. But you could write $\land (x\not\in[-3,4])$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So $x\in\mathbb(R)\wedge(x\notin[-3,4]])$ or would that work by itself? Would $\notin$ include non-real numbers?

Comment: I should have explained what's wrong with $\lnot[-3,4]$. The symbol $\lnot$ is for logical negation of a **formula**, and $[-3,4]$ is not a formula.

Comment: @AndréNicolas oh, okay. I think I got it now, logical negation won't work directly on a set, only on a formula. So I'd need to put $x\in$ or something to make it a formula.  :) Could you maybe put that in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Well, it is not clear whether the $\mathbb{R}$ stuff is needed, because in this context quantification is over the reals. So I think one could leave it out but your teacher might not agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put it that way, the part after $\land$  could be  $\lnot(x\in[-3,4])$. That makes it correct, but in my view not an improvement over $x\in((-\infty,-3)\cup (4,\infty))$.

Or else we can write $(x\not\in[-3,4])$.

One reason $\lnot[-3,4]$ is not correct is that $\lnot$ is a symbol for *logical negation*. So $\lnot\varphi$ is well-formed only when $\varphi$ is a *formula*. And $[-3,4]$ is not a formula.